# Why can't I cast an object of type View to KeyboardView

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-view

I have defined a custom KeyboardView like this:

```
    public class MyKeyboardView extends KeyboardView
    {
        public MyKeyboardView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
        {
            super(context, attrs);
            ...
```

and somewhere in my code I have:

```
    MyKeyboardView myKbView = (MyKeyboardView) myViewGroup.findViewWithTag("MyKeyboardView");
```

where myViewGroup comes from inflating the following xml file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <android.gesture.GestureOverlayView
        android:id="@+id/gestureOverlayView"
        android:gestureColor="#00000000"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:tag="MyGestureOverlayView"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView
            android:id="@+id/keyboard"
            android:keyBackground="@drawable/orange_keyboard_keys_background"
            android:keyTextColor="#ff8710"
            android:background="#4c4c4c"
            android:tag="MyKeyboardView"
            android:keyTextSize="21sp"
            android:keyPreviewLayout="@layout/key_preview_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </android.gesture.GestureOverlayView>

</LinearLayout>
```

and this is what Logcat says:

```
    03-09 22:52:29.274: E/deliKey(21719): java.lang.ClassCastException:
    android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView cannot be cast to
    com.parasum.delikey.MyKeyboardView
```

**WHY?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView and com.parasum.delikey.MyKeyboardView are indeed descendants of View, but neither is a descendant of the other. It's analogous to Views and Strings. They're both descendants of Object, but you can't cast between them.

Comment: It was a great answer. I completely got it. Thank you

Comment: Well, unfortunately this is not true. In your code you have `MyKeyboardView extends KeyboardView` - MyKeyboardView is a descendant of KeyboardView. This is not the problem here.

Comment: To be honest, the xml file is in a different apk file. I'm trying to have a theme plugin for my application. I'm getting disappointed :-( I have absolutely no idea why I can't cast it.

Comment: Based on the error message, it appears the KeyboardView in your Java file is a com.parasum.delikey.MyKeyboardView while the one in the XML is a android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView. That could be caused by problem with your import statements. Please show them to us.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot cast this way as you declared the view in XML as `android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView`.

You need to change your XML and declare it as `MyKeyboardView`:

```
<com.parasum.delikey.MyKeyboardView
        android:id="@+id/keyboard"
        android:keyBackground="@drawable/orange_keyboard_keys_background"
        android:keyTextColor="#ff8710"
        android:background="#4c4c4c"
        android:tag="MyKeyboardView"
        android:keyTextSize="21sp"
        android:keyPreviewLayout="@layout/key_preview_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

---

You currently declare your visual element as `KeyboardView` class. Then you try to cast it to `MyKeyboardView` class. This cannot work as a class cannot be cast to a class that inherits from it (a class cannot be cast to its child class). This is the way it works in Java.

Comment: Just WHY?! aren't both of them instances of View?

Comment: @Joseph_Marzbani They are. But you're casting it to `MyKeyboardView` specifically. MyKeyboardView myKbView = **(MyKeyboardView)** myViewGroup.findViewWithTag("MyKeyboardView");

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. Just for your info, my xml is in another apk and I cannot use <com.parasum.delikey.MyKeyboardView because there, there's no idea what MyKeyboardView is.

Comment: then how we can cast a View object to, for example, a Button. You remember?: Button btn = (Button) findViewById();

Comment: @Joseph_Marzbani You can do that because you declare this object as `Button` in your XML. Try declaring something as `View` in XML and then casting it.

Comment: I tried to put additional explanation in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are not creating a `com.parasum.delikey.MyKeyboardView` but rather a `android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView`.

Try replacing the line in your layout xml:

```
<android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView
```

with

```
<com.parasum.delikey.MyKeyboardView
```

Comment: Just WHY?! aren't both of them instances of View?